# Pasar resultado de un programa en java a una base de datos en PostgreSQL

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql

El resultado de un token hecho en Java (Netbeans) pasarlo directo a una base de datos generada en PostgreSQL.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. ¿Qué es lo que haz intentado hasta el momento? Te recomiendo que te pase por el [tour] y seguido por la página [ask] para que puedas mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega un [mcve]